# Is there a CSS/HTML way to cut multiple shapes out of the top/bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm honestly not sure where to begin on this one (I'm a graphic designer digging a bit deeper into HTML/CSS, but my current experience is rather slim, so this problem is beyond my ability at the moment):

In part of my newest site design I've broken up sections of the site with banded shades: sections alternate between having the standard page background and applying a 10% black transparency overlay, which serves to distinguish the next section.

The problem is that every new section is supposed to have a block of three centered arrows cut out of the darker (or lighter) shade above, like so:

[image]

I know how I could manage this with images, but since the background is a repeating pattern that solution doesn't really work.

Any advice/tips that could help me solve this problem? Basically, all light sections need to begin with three arrows of 10% black transparency, and all dark sections need to begin with three arrows cut out of the 10% transparency background.

Is there an HTML/CSS based way to do this?

Comment: You said "since the background is a repeating pattern that solution doesn't really work".
Maybe this page will help you:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp

Comment: @ItayItai not really. w3schools is a terrible resource. Did you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat ?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I think it's good enough to understand a simple thing like background-repeat :) But I'll try giving better resources next time.

Comment: I think I may not have explained properly: the background already repeats. The triangles are only to separate sections. I can't simply drop in the triangles as images, as the subtle background pattern repeats throughout every section, so if they're not cut-outs that show the page background I'd get visual breaks as the user scrolls.

In short, I can't simply make images of the triangles without wrecking the ability to seamlessly scroll the site and have the background pattern remain intact.

Comment: Do both the dark and light portions have a repeating background or just one of them?

Answer (score 3):

### Container with trapezoid top border

**Trapezoid:**
I add the desired border on the top with a pseudo-element **[::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)**.
Choose to display this content as a block this way it gets the size of its container.
Positioned this element relative so it is not displayed inside its container. `position:relative;` & `top: -30px;`
The border got a static 30px, and that's why its displayed -30px higher so its exactly above our .cut-out.

**Transparency:**
Setting the color with **[rgba()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba())** lets you set the opacity of the color.
So rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) sets the container/trapezoid to have a opacity of 10%. where a last value of 1 would equal 100% opacity. (Where you would use [rgb()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()) instead)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.cut-out {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.cut-out::before {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
}
.stop {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="cut-out">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, </div><!--
--><div class="cut-out" style="width:150px;">Lorem ipsum dollar si amet, </div><!--
--><div class="cut-out" style="width:250px;"></div><!--
--><div class="cut-out"></div>
  <div class="stop"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/7XwUQ/) that should help you out. This is done using simple CSS, and I'm just illustrating it here. You can adapt this to match your needs.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="cutout"></div>
```

And the CSS

```
.cutout {
    width: 100px;
    height: 0px;
    background: none;
    border-bottom: solid 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-right: solid 30px transparent;
    border-left: solid 30px transparent;
    border-top: solid 0 transparent;
}
```

This will give you one of the elements to be repeated. To get some understanding of how this works, check out the following CSS in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/godfrzero/7XwUQ/1/):

```
.cutout {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-bottom: solid 30px rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
    border-right: solid 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-left: solid 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    border-top: solid 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Basically, we're assigning `transparent` color to the right and left borders, and giving the `div` a height of 0. This means only the bottom border remains visible, and a trapezoidal shape is formed because of the border width.

**Edit:** Looks like the links posted by @Myke showcase this already, I recommend playing around with code like this until you get a good idea of how to render similar shapes.